# Google_chrome tab crashing issue on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome

some time I'm getting this issue on Google chrome tab changes, using Ubuntu 22.04. I did complete all the updates even Ubuntu and applications,
in Chrome.

- *Performance* -> *Memory saver*-> turned off
- *Settings* -> *System* -> *Use hardware acceleration when available* = turned off
- *Settings* -> *System* -> *Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed* = turned off

I'm facing the same issue sometimes, sometimes it is working good.

[image]